# login to an custom oauth2.0 server using the same tokens issued by the auth server

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, owin, c#-5.0, owin-middleware

I have implemented a simple authorization server with C# using the following [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server). This works fine for my other applications that I built.

The problem arises when I want to login to the Auth server itself to manage user settings like 'change password' or 'change email'. I want to show a front-end, but when I use the `[Authorize]` tag on the endpoint, my incoming `User` is always `null`, while it works fine on the other applications.

I tried setting the [`DefaultAuthenticationType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.defaultauthenticationtypes(v=vs.108).aspx) to different values but to no avail.

How is it possible to log in to the Auth server with the same token it generates?

EDIT:
To make the flow more obvious:
I have a website, api and an authorization server.
When users want to login to the website, they redirect to the authorization server to authenticate and authorize. This is through the oauth2.0 authorization code grant flow. The access token is then used to retrieve information from the api that is protected with the [`Authorize`] tag. This works.

What I want now is that I can redirect to a specific 'change password' view on the authorization server itself, and this has to be protected with [`Authorize`] as well. This does not work, as the `user` will be `null`.

EDIT2: The [Authorize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) tag automatically protects api/view endpoints in c# aspnet mvc/api.

Edit3: This is how I configure my Auth server.

```
public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app, IUnityContainer container)
    {
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            LogoutPath = new PathString("/Account/Logout"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider()
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationIdentityUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => manager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie))
            }
        });

        OAuthBearerOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions();

        OAuthBearerServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/authorize"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
            Provider = container.Resolve<SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider>(),
            RefreshTokenProvider = container.Resolve<SimpleRefreshTokenProvider>(),
            AuthorizationCodeProvider = container.Resolve<SimpleAuthorizationCodeProvider>()
        };

        // Token Generation
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthBearerServerOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(OAuthBearerOptions);
        var configuration = container.Resolve<IConfiguration>().Get<AuthServiceSettings>("Application");

        // Configure Google
        GoogleAuthOptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
        {
            ClientId = configuration.GoogleSettings.ClientId,
            ClientSecret = configuration.GoogleSettings.ClientSecret,
            Provider = new GoogleAuthProvider()
        };
        GoogleAuthOptions.Scope.Add("email");
        GoogleAuthOptions.Scope.Add("openid");
        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(GoogleAuthOptions);

        //Configure Facebook External Login
        FacebookAuthOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AppId = configuration.FacebookSettings.AppId,
            AppSecret = configuration.FacebookSettings.AppSecret,
            Provider = new FacebookAuthProvider(),
            BackchannelHttpHandler = new FacebookBackChannelHandler(),
            UserInformationEndpoint = configuration.FacebookSettings.UserInformationEndpoint
        };
        FacebookAuthOptions.Scope.Add("email");
        FacebookAuthOptions.Scope.Add("public_profile");
        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(FacebookAuthOptions);
    }
```

EDIT4: Debug information when checking variables:

```
>> HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
false
>> System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated
true
```

No idea why these identities are not the same... but based on this I could write my own authorize tag and use that, but I'm reluctant to use something from Thread because I don't know if this works on multiple threads.

Comment: So, Can you login to your Auth server? - it will give you any token? - where is that `[Authorize]` and why ?, ... Please provide more info -HTH ;).

Comment: i'll edit the question to make it more clear

Comment: I want users to change their own password by showing a protected view.

Comment: If you have that view just route them to that view with their token then post your `ChangePasswordCommand` to your API that has `[Authorize]` att, but with their token in the header of request, I think this should work, I mean when you have token in your view it's not matter where are you for `[Authorize]` tag ;).

Comment: I am doing that, but it doesn't enter my controller endpoint because according to the Authorize tag, the user is null and not authenticated, while the token is valid.

Comment: While inside a controller endpoint, the controller knows a `User` object that represents the user. this should be the content of the access token as well. But because of the authorize tag, I never enter the method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153608/discussion-between-sha-t-and-lars-celie).